# How this bitwise operation work?

Tags: c++

This code confuses me a lot:

```
bool b = 8 & 7 == 0; //b == false
std::cout << 8 & 7; //Outputs 0
```

Why does it do that?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence In fact, I get a [compiler warning](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/acc44965f2315b25).

Comment: Who is teaching you to write such a code?

Answer (score 8):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

`==` is executed/evaluated before `&` so you get:

```
bool b = 8 & 7 == 0; //==>

//  7==0 --> 0
//  8 & 0 --> 0 (which is 'false')
//  ==> b is false
```

To get what you expect just add `()`:

```
bool b = (8 & 7) == 0; // will be evaluated as 'true'
```

Answer (score 5):

Because `==` has precedence over `&`. So, Your expression is equivalent to:

```
( 8 & (7==0))
```

which equals 0.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that expression:

```
8 & 7 == 0;
```

is equal to:

```
8 & ( 7 == 0 );
```

so to fix it use brackets explicitly:

```
( 8 & 7 ) == 0;
```

you should always use brackets when you unsure in evaluation order.

Answer (score 0):

first line has been coverred,
for second line since 8 = 1000 and 7 = 0111, the result is 0, whic is expected